# datastore count query fetchOptions

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

I want to do the following:

```
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
int count = pq.countEntities(FetchOptions.ALL);
```

But there is no *ALL* option. So how do I do it?

For context, say I want to count all entry in my table where color is orange.

If I can't do this directly using `DatastoreService`, can I use **Datanucleus's JPA**? As in do they support `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` for the appengine datastore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can count total no of record using following code.

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query qry = new com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query("EntityName");
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
int totalCount = datastoreService.prepare(qry).countEntities(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
```

i hope it will help you.

Comment: Does `withDefaults()` not return only up to 1000 or some sort of limit?

Comment: withDefaults() return total record from entity.yes its return more than 1000 record too because i already read more than 1000 record using this code.

Comment: The 1000 limit did exist but it was lifted.

Comment: This method works, but it can time out depending on how many items you have. If having too many entries is a possibility, check into Datastore Statistics, keeping a counter in the datastore, or sharding counters for a solution that scales properly. https://blog.svpino.com/2015/03/08/how-to-count-all-entries-of-a-given-type-in-the-app-engine-datastore

Answer (score 2):

The marked answer is not correct, it will max out in 1000

This is how one will get correct count

```
DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
 Query query = new Query("__Stat_Kind__");
 Query.Filter eqf = new Query.FilterPredicate("kind_name",
                            Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL,
                            "MY_ENTITY_KIND");
query.setFilter(eqf);
Entity entityStat = ds.prepare(query).asSingleEntity();
Long totalEntities = (Long) entityStat.getProperty("count");
```

Comment: having problem using datastore, if you have any post that it was used

Comment: what exceptions are you getting ?

Comment: null pointer exception, when i read on , they said it is not the most efficient as it will not give the real time count of the record, and it updates like 10hrs before getting the next total count

Comment: the best way to go about this is sharding

Comment: Yes and No, If you have massive amount of data the sharding or map reduce type realtime count isn't an efficient way to go. Maybe keeping temporary count in mem-cahe of every write is abetter idea.

Comment: yea is in the implementation of sharding from their documentation, use the mem_cache and then make it expire for every 60 seconds , so you use the mem_cache when the user do increment under the 60 seconds (so it dont get too bucky). very efficient from Brett Slatkin (Google), thats why it efficient because of the implementation of the mem_cache

Comment: This will only work when running deployed.  When running on a local dev GAE instance, entityStat will come back as null.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google's plugin for DataNucleus, which seems to [show support for count()](https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/appengine/datanucleus/query/DatastoreQuery.java#577)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using the gae-eclipse-plugin, which datanucleus is part of. I don't understand what the link you provide says. Do you mind correcting the following example?: `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items i WHERE i.color = :color"`. Or would that query be correct the way I have it? I remember reading some where that the `*` is not supported.

Comment: some eclipse plugin won't do persistence. The jar called "datanucleus-appengine" is obviously what GAE refer to as JPA and I already linked you the source code for that plugin, and it shows they support count() so why not just try it ?

Comment: Thanks. +1. I am not able to test yet, but supposedly `count(p)` will work.

Answer (score 1):

This Old but should help for new developers seeking for a way out.

The best way to go about this is using Sharding Counter Techniques, as you save on the entity you know would scale with time, use sharding counter to get the total number of record as it is inserted or the entity group is updated by new record, with this you can get the total number of counter and their corresponding counts which will sum up to give the actual count of the total element in the datastore table or kind.

Use this link for help on how to go about it, for better understanding watch the google i/o 2008 on scaling web applications [here](https://sites.google.com/site/io/building-scalable-web-applications-with-google-app-engine), after that you move to this documentation on appengine [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters?csw=1#more-info), so you get the grasp of it quickly, and also there is a github example test too.

For added example use this link [Blog Tutorial](http://avianey.blogspot.com.ng/2012/01/generic-jpa-sharded-counter-for-google.html) which explained a simple example.